# Is there a way to query blockchain stored data

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I have a single smart contract which stores the investor details record and i have a global variable in that smart contract which stores the total number of investors when each investor records creates this gets incremented. Now I have two dapp one is to create the investor record which will communicate to the smart contract. Another dapp which shows the total number of investors. Is there any way i can fetch the total number of investors (uisng ABI of the contract) from the blockchain rather than calling any function from the smart contract